# Spoof ip address for iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, ip-address

If I have a webpage with an iframe to another website, can I spoof the user's ip address so that the iframe sees the ip address I want instead of the user's real ip address?

Comment: I suppose you could, but then that other IP address would receive the data !

Comment: The more standard behaviour would be to include the user's IP in [the `X-Forwarded-For` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

Answer (score 3):

No.

You could proxy the request, but you can't make the client spoof a request to another site.

Comment: though the effect of proxying is the same from the target's point of view.

Comment: @jiggunjer — But is limited to IP addresses that you control.